# sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable.Please help me

Tags: linux, sudo

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
```

''
I could not able to do anything please help me to fix this issue .Thanks advance!
''

Comment: Show the rights with: ```ls -la /etc/sudoers``` - It should be: ```-r--r----- 1 root root 494 Nov  3  2009 /etc/sudoers``` - To fix it see the answers ;-) - But you have to be the super user: root to do that

Answer (score 2):

You should definetly reduce rights for this file, by default it's

```
440
```

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-125:~$ sudo chmod o-rwx /etc/sudoers
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin


getting again same error

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-125:~$ sudo su
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-125:~$

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-125:~$ ll /etc/sudoers
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 785 Mar 16 09:12 /etc/sudoers*
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-125:~$

Comment: this is production VM i'm not getting any idea how to fix this

Comment: @Haridvpsk you should try `pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers` without reboot

Comment: kexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/bin/chmod' as the super user
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password:

Comment: i have not set any password for the users ubuntu & root

Comment: Are you using a private key?

Comment: yes I'm using private key to connect the VM

Comment: As far as i know, you can't get privelege escalation with pkexec without password any simple way. Try contacting your ISP to find password related to the default account.

Comment: don't have password  for the user and there is know default password for the same as it is aws ec2 machine

Answer (score 2):

This should fix it :

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/sudoers
sudo chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
```

Answer (score 1):

You messed your Linux system, or you have some malware or some virus on it.

Maybe you could try

```
chmod o-rwx /etc/sudoers
```

as root